# Erro condicional visualg

Tags: visualg

```
 Algoritmo "SIMULAÇÃO JOGO GENIUS"
 Descrição   : Aqui você descreve o que o programa faz! (função)
 Autor(a)    : Nome do(a) aluno(a)
 Data atual  : 27/09/2019
Var
   randon:vetor[0..3]de inteiro
   posicao,a,b,c,d,nun1,nun2,nun3,nun4: inteiro
   menu: caractere

procedimento menu()
inicio

   Escreval("-------------------------------")
   Escreval("BEM VINDO AO SIMON GENIUS")
   Escreval("-------------------------------")

   Escreval("VAMOS LA")
   Escreval("-------------------------------")
fimprocedimento

Inicio
   menu()

   randon[0]<-1
   randon[1]<-2
   randon[2]<-3
   randon[3]<-4

   a<-Randi(4)

   randon[0]<-1
   randon[1]<-2
   randon[2]<-3
   randon[3]<-4

   b<-Randi(4)

   randon[0]<-1
   randon[1]<-2
   randon[2]<-3
   randon[3]<-4

   c<-Randi(4)

   randon[0]<-1
   randon[1]<-2
   randon[2]<-3
   randon[3]<-4

   d<-Randi(4)

   escreval(randon[a], randon, randon[c], randon[d])


   escreval("Digite o 1o numero da sequencia: ")
   leia(nun1)
   escreval("Digite o 2o numero da sequencia: ")
   leia(nun2)
   escreval("Digite o 3o numero da sequencia: ")
   leia(nun3)
   escreval("Digite o 4o numero da sequencia: ")
   leia(nun4)

   Se (randon(a) <> nun1) e (randon(b) <> nun2) e (randon(c) <> nun3) e (randon(d) <> nun4) então
   escreval("você errou! Tente novamente!!")
   senao
      escreval("Parabens! você ganhou!!")
   fimse
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Bom dia grupo! Estou tentando comparar o resultado randomico com a resposta que o usuário envia mas dá erro nesta condicional simples

Comment: Aqui: escreval(randon[a], randon, randon[c], randon[d]) você se esqueceu do índice do segundo parâmetro da função escreval e aqui: Se (randon(a) <> nun1) e (randon(b) <> nun2) e (randon(c) <> nun3) e (randon(d) <> nun4) então você trocou o [] por () ao se referir a um elemento do vetor.

Comment: Corrigi com atenção o que vc falou e ficou ok! obrigado! Tb troquei o <> por =  pois faz mais sentido e bateu certinho. Agora vou tentar resolver o problema de fazer a sequencia piscar na tela do visualg, acho que com o timer resolvo isso

Comment: Creio que o VisuAlg é muito simplório para você fazer tal efeito.

Comment: Tb imagino isso mas estou querendo fazer tipo um "repita até" com timer .. pensando aqui

Comment: para ele mostrar a sequencia e depois o usuario digitar pois neste que eu fiz a sequencia aparece direto